# Smarty date_format with default

Tags: smarty

I want something like this - where the date could be empty:

`{$VERTRAGSDATUM|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y"|default:'________________'}`

But it gives me only "Undefined index" errors.
When changing the order to default at first it gives me the current date. :-/

I've a lot of this date fields and don't want to ask if isset...  so is there perhaps a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle null value of date using if else condition. When date value is null `date_format` is raising error. So need to handle that before passing to date_format. Here is updated code.

```
{if $VERTRAGSDATUM} 
  // use default here
{else} 
  {$VERTRAGSDATUM|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thx - but that is not the one-liner I wanted. You don't want this, when you have 43 date fields in a form. ^^

Comment: May be you can use ternary operator for smarty like this may this help:  
 {$VERTRAGSDATUM ?  ($VERTRAGSDATUM|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y) : "______"}